# How to debug asset precompilation errors in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rake, precompile

**Command:** *(ran in console on local environment)*

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
```

**What happens:**

A lot of assets get precompiled. Suddenly precompilation stops with error.

```
I, [2017-06-08T15:31:19.726874 #31286]  INFO -- : Writing /path/jquery.min-23476(...)79529.map
    rake aborted!
    ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: Unexpected character '`' (line: 5185, col: 10, pos: 1741977)

    Error
        at new JS_Parse_Error (/private/var/folders/qz/8thdm5t122s725szpkpsxcdr0000gn/T/execjs20170608-31286-1f6tv61js:3623:11948)
```

How do you approach debugging of such a challenge?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is due to [ES6 Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) are not being detected properly. A workaround would be replacing template literals with single quotes.

A very good example of this can be seen [here](http://qiita.com/HyAnVeEx/items/7b20a68efb10056cbed3)